# For loop i variable not in order

Tags: node.js, for-loop

Sorry that my title is vague I don't know what to call it.

I am making a kahoot spammer website. The bots are supposed to spawn into the kahoot in ascending order e.g. testbot1 --> testbot2 --> testbot3 etc. However it always ends up like this: [image: Kahoot bots]

In console it shows the problem too:
[image: Console bots]

I have a command in the server.js which loops the command file to spam bots:

`for(var i=0;numberOfBots>i;i++){
    runKahootIndex.run(pin, name, command, i)
  }`

And then in that file the code is:

```
  var client = new Kahoot;
  client.join(pin, `${name}${numIDCounter}`) // the "numIDCounter" is just the i variable from server.js
```

I have no idea what is causing this problem and also every time the file tries to spawn a bot that is already in a game errors start popping up but the file still keeps on running. The errors are these but I don't think they would be useful:
[image: Console Error 1]
[image: Console Error 2]

Edit: I have added a function like this in my program but it hasn't fixed it:

```
function sleep(millis) {
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
```

}

**How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.**

Comment: this smells like a network lag thing. what happens if you have the process sleep for a few seconds before each one?

Comment: well... you have two options. Ignore it, or force your program to only perform one of each async action at a time, thus significantly increasing the amount of time required to complete( moreso the more bots you have.)

Comment: The timeout is likely being thrown by the server you are connecting to because you're sending it hundreds of requests instantly and it just can't handle it.

Comment: @KevinB I have updated my question

Comment: @castis I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about kahoot but it looks like the bots are being created asynchronously. Try creating the bots with a promise inside the for loop.